overwiting with backspace leaving an empty line
Is there a one-line way to enforce gfortran to overwrite the last line written in an output file with a blank space, so the next line is written just below an empty line and not overwriting the previous one ? backspace(fileunit) places the cursor at the beginning of that line but then the next line is written right there thus not leaving a blank line. Granted, one could do
backspace(fileunit)
write(fileunit)

which leaves the blank line, but I would like something like
backspace (fileunit,advance='yes') if that exists (that is, a single-line command). Previously in my code, I've used the write command with the advance='no' option, but I guess that's irrelevant

Be aware that gfortran is just one compiler of many. You should want something in standard Fortran. However, I do not think there is anything. It is too specialized. You can always write a subroutine that executes those two commands.

Sounds like an xy problem.  Do you have to do this because of the way the output and looping is done in the code?

Don't understand advance. Fortran 2018 example WRITE (*, FMT=’(A)’, ADVANCE=’NO’) ’CONTINUE?(Y/N): ’ output a prompt without LF (or CR+LF etc). backspace(fileunit) - moves back one character, after which it is positioned after the previous LF, it does not write anything.

@Serge3leo I use gcc compiler, where backspace(fileunit) does not move back one single character but the whole row, cancelling it if it was generated with write. And it looks like it places the prompt at the end of the preceding row.
